# Insert all records into junction table in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, insert, many-to-many, junction-table

I have a next tables: quiz, question, and question_quiz. I have a many-to-many relationship. 
Insertion work right for table quiz and question, but in table question_quiz inserted only single record.

My tables

"question", it's all right.

```
+----+--------+
| id | title  |
+----+--------+
| 61 | Title1 |
| 62 | Title2 |
| 63 | Title3 |
+----+--------+
```

"quiz", it's all right.

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | status |
+----+-------+--------+
| 27 | Name1 |      0 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

"question_quiz"

```
+-------------+---------+
| question_id | quiz_id |
+-------------+---------+
|          61 |      27 |
+-------------+---------+
```

In last table must be inserted 61,62,63 quiestion_id, but inserted only single record.

Fragment of my controller.

```
   $quiz = new Quiz();
   $question = new Question();
   $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('quiz', QuizType::class, $quiz);
   $quiz->getQuestions()->add($question);
   $question->addQuiz($quiz);
   $form->handleRequest($request);
   if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($quiz);
      $em->persist($question);
      $em->flush();
}
```

The call evidence of a question entity.

```
  $quiz->getQuestions()->add($question);
  $question->addQuiz($quiz);
```

I use the collection type, and I can insert any number of questions.

**UPDATE QuizType form.**

```
class QuizType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('attr' => ['class' => 'form-control name-quiz'], 'label' => 'Name Quiz'))
            ->add('status', CheckboxType::class, array(
                'label'    => 'Status Quiz',
                'required' => false))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Add', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']]);
        $builder
            ->add('questions', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => QuestionType::class,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
                'allow_add' => true,
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Quiz::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

if I debug the method `addQuestion()` I got error INSERT INTO question (title) VALUES (?)' with params [null]. But if I dubug method addQuiz I get

```
   Question {#583 ▼
  -id: null
  -title: "123"
  -quiz: ArrayCollection {#584 ▼
    -elements: array:1 [▼
      0 => Quiz {#581 ▼
        -id: null
        -name: "123"
        -questions: ArrayCollection {#580 ▶}
        -status: false
      }
    ]
  }
  -answers: ArrayCollection {#585 ▶}
}
```

The debug $form->get('questions')->getData() return

```
ArrayCollection {#733 ▼
  -elements: array:2 [▼
    0 => Question {#736 ▶}
    1 => Question {#981 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `QuizType` please? It looks like the mapping from the submitted data to your `Quiz` entity does not work as you expect it to do.

Comment: @xabbuhI I updated.

Comment: Oh, and can you also show your `Quiz` and `Question` entities?

Comment: @xabbuh please, you can see here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954652/insert-into-junction-table-with-relationship-many-to-many-in-symfony-4

Comment: I wonder if `$this->questions[] = $question;` is ever called and if that really works. `$this->questions` in your `Quiz` entity is a Doctrine collection. So I would have expected this line to be `$this->questions->add($question);`.

Comment: @xabbuh Well, I did, but it inserts one record still, instead all records.

Comment: Can you debug if the `addQuestion()` method is ever called when your form is submitted? Can you also debug the value of `$form->get('questions')->getData()`?

Comment: @xabbuh I updated my question.

Comment: the problem in your case -> you call `persist()` only on `$quiz` and `$question`. After submitting you get another one, but without `cascade={"persist"}`, you have to loop over `$quiz->getQuestions()` and persist all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `Quiz` and `Question` entities - it is hard to tell. BUT

I think the problem is in your controller.

```
 $quiz = new Quiz();
 $question = new Question();
 //...
 $question->addQuiz($quiz);
```

So you create a new Quiz, which should have multiple questions, right?
But you asign a question only once..

```
$question->addQuiz($quiz);
```

so the right way would be like (a bit verbose so you can get the point)

```
$quiz = new Quiz();
//Q 1
$question_1 = new Question('Title1'); 
$quiz->addQuestion( $question_1 ); 
//Q 2
$question_2 = new Question('Title2'); 
$quiz->addQuestion( $question_2 );
//Q 3
$question_2 = new Question('Title3'); 
$quiz->addQuestion( $question_3 );

$em->persist($question_1);
$em->persist($question_2);
$em->persist($question_2);
$em->persist($quiz);
$em->flush();
```

Take a look at this example (https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3121916) for ManyToMany relation and especial to `addUSerGroup()` and `addUser()` methods.

Try the suggested method in a controller (without form) and see if it works and if you get more than one rows into `question_quiz` table

**UPDATE:**

I think the "magic" you're looking for is `cascade={"persist"}` in your Quiz Entity. Take a look at this article (https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/collections/add-new-collection-cascade-persist). Even though the video isn't free, the text is fine.

1)set up `cascade` in yout entity

2)updated you `addQuestion()` method in Quiz class like following

```
public function addQuestion(Question $question)
{
  // do not add same questions more than once. 
  if ($this->questions->contains($question)) {
    return;
  }
  $this->questions[] = $question; // to add new question to that quiz
  $question->addQuiz($this); // this quiz now also belongs to a question
}
```

3) get embed collection to work with `prototype` => http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html. So you can add new Questions on the fly

4)After submit, just call:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
   $quiz = $form->getData();
   $em->persist($quiz);
   $em->flush();
}
```

4.1)If that doesn't work, try looping over the **submitted** collection of questions

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
   $quiz = $form->getData();
   // since getQuestions() gives you an ArrayCollection, isEmpty is a built in method
   if(!$quiz->getQuestions()->isEmpty())
   {
     // this is kinda bad, but you'll have to debug and play around
     foreach ($quiz->getQuestions() as $new_question)
     {
       $em->persist($new_question);
     }
   }
   $em->persist($quiz);
   $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: That don't work for me, because I want inserting any number of questions. In you example I can only add the 3 question. I saw link already. I tried join table and join column, but it don't work for me.

Comment: that is not correct. with that approach, you can add as many questions to your quiz as you want. Just for demonstration I created three questions and added each of them to a single quiz.
If you'll add `cascade={"persist"}` to your Quiz manytomany annotation you'll get auto-persist, so you don't need call `$em->persist($quesion_X)` manually

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. I post my code maybe it will help somebody.

My entity `Question`

```
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Quiz", inversedBy="questions")
 */
private $quiz;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->quiz = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTitle(): ?string
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function setTitle(string $title): self
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}


/**
 * @return Collection|Quiz[]
 */
public function getQuiz(): Collection
{
    return $this->quiz;
}

public function addQuiz(Quiz $quiz): self
{
    if (!$this->quiz->contains($quiz)) {
        $this->quiz[] = $quiz;
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeQuiz(Quiz $quiz): self
{
    if ($this->quiz->contains($quiz)) {
        $this->quiz->removeElement($quiz);
    }

    return $this;
    }
}
```

My Entity `Quiz`

```
class Quiz
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191)
 */
private $name;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", mappedBy="quiz", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $questions;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $status;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->questions = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Question[]
 */
public function getQuestions(): Collection
{
    return $this->questions;
}

public function addQuestion(Question $question): self
{
    if (!$this->questions->contains($question)) {
        $this->questions[] = $question;
        $question->addQuiz($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeQuestion(Question $question): self
{
    if ($this->questions->contains($question)) {
        $this->questions->removeElement($question);
        $question->removeQuiz($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function getStatus(): ?bool
{
    return $this->status;
}

public function setStatus(bool $status): self
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
   }
}
```

`QuestionType` form

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextareaType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'), 'label' => false));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Question::class
        ]);
    }
```

`QuizType` form

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('attr' => ['class' => 'form-control name-quiz'], 'label' => 'Name quiz'))
            ->add('status', CheckboxType::class, array(
                'label'    => 'Status quiz',
                'required' => false))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Add', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']]);
        $builder
            ->add('questions', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => QuestionType::class,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Quiz::class
        ]);
    }
```

And finally my controller

```
    $quiz = new Quiz();
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('quiz', QuizType::class, $quiz);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($quiz);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');

    }
```

It's works, yea :) Thanks all.